# Church's Thesis

Tags: logic, computability

If we let $f$ be a computable function and define $h(x) = 1$, if $x$ is an element of $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ and undefined otherwise.

I am trying to prove that h is computable via Church's Thesis.

So the idea is that I can say that given $x$, compute $f$. If the computation stops, then set $h(x) = 1$, otherwise continue indefinitely.

But this is not very rigorous in the aspect of URM computability and I need help in polishing this claim. Thanks

Comment: "... let f be a computable function.... I am trying to prove that f is computable." Huh?

Comment: For any TM, it is easy to put a little bit of code at the end to erase the answer $f(x)$ and write a $1$.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to prove $h$ computable?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching the typo

Comment: I tweaked the tags. This is a straight-up computability question, it's not really related to incompleteness or computational complexity.

Comment: @BuddyHolly: Depends how technically minded the course is. To me the informal version is enough.

Comment: The solution Hurkul has is OK, but it is not very complete, can someone elaborate on it, and explain it? And how did it use Church's thesis?

Answer (score 4):

A better description of the algorithm $h$ would be:

- Given input $x$:

  - Emulate the calculation of $f(x)$
  - Output 1

Comment: This is good, do you mind adding some more details and explain where Church's thesis was implemented?

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to do it "via Church's thesis" then you don't want to be "very rigorous", you just want to give a ''sufficiently'' detailed argument that the function is computable by a human. The argument you gave is sufficiently detailed for that purpose; the sentence you wrote clearly describes the algorithm that is needed to compute $h$.

This method of showing that a function is computable is called "weak Church's thesis" by Rogers. The idea is to give a description of the algorithm that is precise enough for the reader to see that the function is computable, without writing a detailed program for the function.  Of course, the reader could come back and ask for a more detailed explanation, but in practice it is often possible to convince the reader that a function is computable without producing a program for it.